# Which database user do you use to connect to pgAdmin3? (PostgreSQL9/CentOS6)

Tags: centos6, postgresql

I've installed pgAdmin3 in my CentOS6. I am using PostgreSQL9.

My problem is that I'm not able to add a server to the pgAdmin3. It gives me an error:

[image]

[image]

I have not a password for the user "postgres" but I've created a postgresql user just like my regular linux user and I'm able to use "psql":

```
[andre@andre ~]$ psql
psql (9.0.4)
Type "help" for help.

andre=> \q
[andre@andre ~]$
```

My question is: How can I use pgAdmin3 in CentOS6. there is any trick? I must to enter with the user "postgres"?

Give me a clue.

Best Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The guru hint is already telling you where to look. You can allow yourself access through the `pg_hba.conf` file.
Since you are connecting locally, you could add a line for local connections to be trusted:

```
host   all   all   127.0.0.1 255.255.255.255   trust
```

If you want to use a password, you could add

```
host   all   all   127.0.0.1 255.255.255.255   <password or md5>
```

[This page](http://developer.postgresql.org/pgdocs/postgres/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) should have more in-depth info on the `pg_hba.conf` file.

EDIT:
The path to `pg_hba.conf` should be `/var/lib/pgsql/data` for 32-bits systems, and `/var/lib64/pgsql/data` for 64-bits systems.

Answer (score 1):

Your clue: read the "Guru Hint" provided.  It tells you how to fix the problem.